# How to get tabs like zipcar app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In the demo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ2EZ_tWsGc at about :22, he clicks the bottom tabbar and a new view slides up.  It has three tabs at the top.

How do you get the three little tabs working in the "Find car by" view?

Also, how did they create the little tab where the "Find car by" text sits?  It is sticking out on its own from the view.

Comment: This is exactly what look I'm trying to achieve - anyone have tips about how to get the animating out to work, with or without an action sheet?  I have seen other posts saying using an action sheet is hacky? The code snippets I found using UIActionSheet just wouldn't work.  Any help or tips would be great?  Take a look at Awsesome Note app, they do it really nicely, with semi-transparent backgrounds - e.g.: http://bridworks.com/anote/en/image/howto/img0703.jpg

Answer (score 3):

> How do you get the three little tabs
>   working in the "Find car by" view?

This looks like ordinary UISegmentedControl.

> Also, how did they create the little
>   tab where the "Find car by" text sits?
>   It is sticking out on its own from the
>   view.

I think that view itself covers all window area but it has transparent background and also background image making it look a fancy shape. So "Find cars by" must be just UILabel or UIButton put in specific view's point.

Answer (score 1):

The view is an action sheet. The buttons on the left are a single segmented control and the button on right is a plain button. The tab is simply drawn and the part of the sheet next to it is made transparent.

Comment: Don't think the view is an action sheet - the background of the view would be modal, and semi-transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple :

1. Add UIView in window, at the bottom
2. Use UIView animation to do the slide effect
3. You can use a UIView black, transparent to simulate a mask