# How to display custom view in UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I have a UIView with a date picker that I'd like to display in an action sheet.  I'm using the following code:

```
-(IBAction) button_click:(id)sender{
    //UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"the title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive" otherButtonTitles:@"other", nil];

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    ActionSheetController *actionSheet = [[ActionSheetController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"ActionSheetView" bundle:nil];    
    [sheet addSubview:actionSheet.view];

    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

What I get is a little bit of the top part of the new view coming up from the bottom and that's it.  If I comment the two middle lines of code and uncomment the top part to display a regular action sheet, it works fine.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class ActionSheetController your own? could you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the behavoir occurs because I haven't used the UIActionSheet constructor properly.  The buttons and title should be included:

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date Picker" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

use UIActionSheetDelegate and after that you can with this delegate add for example a image to button of alertsheet

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{

   UIImageView *sample = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage       
   imageNamed:@"Someimage.png"]];
   [actionSheet addSubView:sample];

}
```

Comment: This would be great if correct.  Fails with: "No visible @interface for 'UIActionSheet' declares the selector 'addSubView:'"

Comment: just lowercase the v..its [actionSheet addSubview:sample];

Comment: You might want to be careful with this. Apple may not like it. From the documentation: "UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, **nor should you add views to its hierarchy**. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:."

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can specify Custom Views in a UIActionSheet. My understanding is that you can only display a title and 1 or more buttons. Below is the description of UIActionSheet in the Apple documentation:

> Use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with a set of alternatives for how to proceed with a given task. You can also use action sheets to prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous action. The action sheet contains an optional title and one or more buttons, each of which corresponds to an action to take.

[UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: If you take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608239/how-to-get-tabs-like-zipcar-app/2608297#2608297, I have a link to the zipcar app, which seems to using a custom action sheet.

Comment: Technically what you are trying to do could be possible after all UIActionSheet is just another type of UIView. My concern is that it you may run into problems when you submit the application to Apple as they expect UIActionSheet to be used in a very specific way as described in the iPhone HIG http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW1 Have you considered creating a custom modal view instead of trying to use UIActionSheet?

Comment: Wouldn't modal view controller hide/disable the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes but so does UIActionSheet. The navigation bar is placed behind a semi-transparent overlay. 

Why would you want access to the navigation bar when displaying a UIActionSheet? It is designed specifically to force the user to select an action or dismiss the view.

What are you trying to achieve with the UIActionSheet that requires a custom view embedded in it? If I had more details I might be able to give a more detailed response.

Comment: take a look at my first comment above about the zipcar app.  That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @4thSpace: True, but you can embed the modal ViewController in a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out an UIActionSheet alternative I made which lets you display custom content views without any dirty hacks: https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGActionSheet It has some other advantages over UIActionSheet as well!